# Using Postgres function vs Trigger

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres so I am trying to understand ideal approaches/and pattern.

I have a table say services_connected which looks like this

```
| column_name  | data_type                |
| ------------ | ------------------------ |
| id           | bigint                   |
| created_at   | timestamp with time zone |
| workspace_id | bigint                   |
| auto_invite  | boolean                  |
| data         | text                     |
| last_synced  | timestamp with time zone |
| service_name | text                     |
| sync_status  | USER-DEFINED             |
| key_id       | uuid                     |
| nonce        | bytea                    |
| service_info | jsonb                    |
```

and another table named `users`.

Whenever something is deleted from `services_connected`, I would want to update for that table from `users`.

Right now, I have function to do it

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.disconnect_service;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.disconnect_service(service_name_value TEXT)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  workspace_id_value BIGINT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'workspace_id')::BIGINT;

BEGIN
  DELETE from services_connected where workspace_id = workspace_id_value and service_name = service_name_value;
  DELETE FROM users_list WHERE workspace_id = workspace_id_value and service_name = service_name_value; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but I was wondering, If I should create trigger for it or not?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_user_data_for_service()
RETURNS trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
  DELETE FROM users_list WHERE workspace_id = old.workspace_id and service_name = old.service_name; 
END;



CREATE trigger "delete_user_data_on_service_disconnect"
after delete on "services_connected"
for each row
execute function delete_user_data_for_service();
```

Can someone please list the pros and cons?

In functions, I guess if either of the query fails, it restores the db to orignal state? but I guess in triggers that won't be the case? So that should be +1 for functions.

Can someone help me in deciding, how do they decide, or in this particular case, what but a better option?

Comment: It looks like you should do neither and use a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option (which is internally implemented as a trigger, but that is irrelevant)

Comment: What does `query fails`mean? Can't find relevant records or a database crash? When the database crashes, nothing happend, all data is safe, just restart the database server.

Comment: A cascading foreign key is the way to go. But you can also do it with a trigger (that only modifies `users_list`).